# Reading from text file and separating the lines read

Tags: java

so this code is meant to open a text file with the correct name, and then it is meant to split each line the program reads after each comma `,` An example from the text file is:

```
Germany,5,3,6,2,3
Argentina,3,5,2,1,1
```

Comment: see  here in the string `"Germany,5,3,6,2,3"` total comma separated values are 6. so its obvious if you try to use `newStrings[6]`, it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: You are trying to read 7 elements (from index 0 till 6) but your example only has 6 elements. So it will fail at this line:     >NewTeam.setTotalPoints(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[6]));

Comment: if i remove "NewTeam.setTotalPoints(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[6]))" i then get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" - Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop maybe collect the teams:

```
List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside the loop check that you have indeed 7 fields (think of empty lines, data errors)

```
if (newStrings.length != 7) {
    System.out.println("Error in line: " + currentLine);
    continue; // Still handle rest
}
```

Furthermore, as you do a split on the entire line, forget the Scanner lineScanner, it is redundant.

```
       while ((currentLine = bufferedReader().readLine()) != null) {
```

or more readable:

```
       for (;;) {
           String currentLine = bufferedReader().readLine();
           if (currentLine == null) {
               break;
           }
```

At the of the loop:

```
           teams.add(newTeam):
```

---

***Something like:***

```
List<Team> readTeams() throws IOException {
    OUDialog.alert("Select input file for " + this.getPoolName());
    String fileName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
    Path aFile = Paths.get(fileName);
    try (BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(aFile)) {
        String currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
        if (currentLine != null && currentLine.equals(this.getPoolName())) {
            List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();

            while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] newStrings = currentLine.split(",");
                if (teams.length == 0) {
                    continue; // Allow empty lines
                }
                if (teams.length != 7) {
                    throw new IOException("Wrong line:" + currentLine);
                }
                Team newTeam = new Team(newStrings[0]);
                newTeam.setWon(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[1]));
                newTeam.setDrawn(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[2]));
                newTeam.setLost(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[3]));
                newTeam.setFourOrMoreTries(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[4]));
                newTeam.setSevenPointsOrLess(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[5]));
                newTeam.setTotalPoints(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[6]));
                teams.add(newTeam);
            }
            return teams;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Wrong file selected");
        }
    } // Closes always.
}
```

This reports errors as exception.

Comment: If i remove the lineScanner the loop does not continue, the currentLine is set to the bufferedReader and checks to see if it is the correct file, if it is then the lineScanner takes over and reads the lines instead. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Okay I have coded it out.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist in the array.  Looking at your code and your sample inputs you're trying to access 7 elements of the array (indices 0-6) but the inputs only have 6 inputs, meaning as soon as it tries to call `NewTeam.setTotalPoints(Integer.valueOf(newStrings[6]));` it will throw an exception.

The easy fix is to validate your array before parsing it: put a `newStrings.length` check to ensure you have enough array elements to parse out all your fields.  Alternately, just match your parsing to your file if you know the file is consistent.